# Tcl nested proc taking output as input in nested proc

Tags: nested, tcl, proc

```
proc str2hex { string } {
    set str [binary scan $string H* hex]
    puts $hex
    regsub -all (..) $hex {\1 } t1
    set res [format "%s" $t1 ]
    return $res 


    proc hex2str { $hex } {
        puts "HIIHI"
        foreach c [split $$hex ""] {
            if {![string is xdigit $c]} {
                return "#invalid $$hex"
            }
        }
        set hexa [binary format H* $$hex]
        return $hexa
    }
}
```

The above is simple code for conversion of string to hexadecimal.I have made nested proc,where a hex from "`set str [binary scan $string H* hex]`" script is taken as input so as to re -convert the hex to string .Plz help me .

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't normally nest procedures inside procedures in Tcl; the results of it are not what you're expecting. Currently, the Tcl `proc` command takes almost no notice of the context in which it is called (except for knowing what the current namespace is), and in particular it does not affect what the “inner” procedure sees for variables.

What's more, `proc` is an ordinary command (that happens to create another command) and must actually be called for it to do anything. Putting it after the only `return` in a procedure will guarantee that it has no effect at all. Tcl's very simple-minded (and predictable) that way.

Finally, it's inadvisable to put `$` in a variable name. It's legal, but the syntax for accessing it is awkward (in your case, it would be `${$hex}`).

---

If you really want local procedure-like things, consider using `apply` and a lambda term. They were introduced in Tcl 8.5.

If you're using Tcl 8.6 (recommended now) then you've got some more elegant ways of doing these two operations:

```
proc str2hex {string {encoding "utf-8"}} {
    binary scan [encoding convertto $encoding $string] cu* bytes
    return [lmap value $bytes {format %02x $value}]
}
proc hex2str {hex {encoding "utf-8"}} {
    return [encoding convertfrom $encoding [binary format H* [join $hex ""]]]
}
```

(The encoding needs to be specified as otherwise there isn't a unique mapping between bytes — which `binary scan` and `binary format` work with — and characters. But we can set a sensible default.)

Comment: Thank you sir @Donal Fellows for your guidance .